# PHP Increasing write to page speed

Tags: php, xml, optimization

I'm currently writing out xml and have done the following:

```
header ("content-type: text/xml");
header ("content-length: ".strlen($xml));
```

$xml being the xml to be written out.  I'm near about 1.8 megs of text (which I found via firebug), it seems as the writing is taking more time than the script to run.. is there a way to increase this write speed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're saying that printing `$xml` to the page is taking longer than the script to run? That's like saying PHP is taking longer than PHP to run. Perhaps you mean the time it takes to download the page's contents?

Comment: sorry let me word it a bit better.. it appears that leading up to the point where I would execute echo($xml); runs in a second, while echoing out the actual $xml element stalls out the browser and takes the majority of time.

Comment: Well, as you said, you're browser is downloading 1.8mb of data which could take a substantial amount of time. Have you looked into gzipping your pages with apache and mod_deflate?

Comment: isn't gzipping your pages turned on by default? I will recheck that, but was fairly certain this was already happening.

Comment: Can content-length echo a cached value? strlen() is kind of expensive. Or is the XML generated from a query? If so, can _that_ length be cached per query? Ie if 10 million poeple request books.xml , unless it changed, strlen() should run only once.

Comment: good to know, didn't know it was an expensive call.  It can't be a cached value, as it's built from a query, Thanks for the info though, I'll be careful where to use it, or maybe try to cache for specific queries.

Comment: No, strlen() isn't expensive if you don't run it a few *millions of times*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you're writing the data. If you're using DOM, consider XMLWriter. It's a bit faster and more streamlined.

If you're homebrewing your XML output, ensure that you aren't appending strings unnecessarily. For instance:

```
echo "<tag>" . $data . "</tag>"; // this is slower
echo '<tag>', $data, '</tag>';   // this is faster
```

The comma operator doesn't create new strings. Also to consider, single quoted strings are slightly faster than double quotes. There is no variable substitution to scan for. Normally, the difference is minimal, but in a tight loop you can definitely see it.

Depending on your data source and how you construct your XML, your processing might be the bottleneck. Try profiling with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and seeing where your bottlenecks actually are.

Comment: Currently using XMLWriter, started with my own, but found i could reduce memory with flushing by using XMLWriter.  I'll take a peak at xdebug.  Thank you

Comment: Another thing to watch out for: make sure output buffering is turned off

Comment: Yes, turned this off once I realized it was on.. that changed things quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Google's results seem to suggest that echo has poor performance for large strings. One solution would be to break the string to be echo'd into chunks;

```
function echobig($string, $bufferSize = 8192)
{
    $splitString = str_split($string, $bufferSize);

    foreach($splitString as $chunk)
        echo $chunk;
}
```

Please note, I've not tested this code out; I found it in the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#50401). Read [this blog post](http://wonko.com/post/seeing_poor_performance_using_phps_echo_statement_heres_why) for someone else who had a similar issue that was solved by splitting the echo string into chunks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying dumping your XML to a temporary file and then using [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) to send the data to the user.